# Точный float с определенным количеством знаков после запятой

Tags: python

Мне нужно разделить два числа, с определенным количеством знаков после запятой. Ответ с англоязычного StackOverflow мне не помог - вместо необходимого `0.000001002003004005006007008009...` выдает `0.000001002003004005005955287066...`. Мне нужно получить из деления двух чисел точный float с определенным количеством знаков после запятой, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` имеет конечную точность - около 17 знаков. Воспользуйтесь десятичной арифметикой [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). Её точность можно регулировать как вам удобно:

> ```
> @>>> from decimal import *
> @>>> getcontext().prec = 6
> @>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
> Decimal('0.142857')
> @>>> getcontext().prec = 28
> @>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
> Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
> @>>> getcontext().prec = 100
> @>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
> Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571429')
> @>>>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
def toFixed(numObj, digits=0):
    return f"{numObj:.{digits}f}"

print(toFixed(3.506754657, 2))
'3.50'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я получил `3.51`, не `3.50`. И пример из вопроса не работает.